# Why are shock absorbers in wishbone suspension systems mounted on the lower control arm?

Tags: suspension, shock-absorber, springs, handling

Is there any particular reason (relating to the sprung mass) for having this kind of setup?

I am yet to see a wishbone suspension with the shocks on the UCA.

Comment: the shocks need X amount of inches of travel otherwise you'd be hitting the bump stop everytime you hit a bump.

Comment: What about this? http://photos1.blogger.com/blogger2/4682/1113101853981372/1600/double-wishbone-suspension.jpg

Answer (score 7):

The late 60s to early 70s mustangs has shocks and springs on the upper control arms. 
[image]

Normally They are installed on the lower control arm to save space. By fitting them between the control arms the towers don't have to be as tall or the shock/spring could be mounted directly to the frame.